# Why can't everything be overloaded in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

It is reasonable that `sizeof` and `typeid` cannot be overloaded, but I can't see the harm in overloading `?:`, `.*` and `.`. Are there technical reasons for this?

Comment: The harm is that operator overloading already makes it difficult to ascertain the meaning of a line of code extracted from a program; allowing overloading of `.` in particular would be a travesty. Conversely, what would be the benefit of allowing this?

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance but is `.*` really an operator or is it just a typo ?

Comment: What would you want to do with an overloaded `.` that you can't do with `->`?

Comment: @Tomalak: You're right that there is a trade-off between readability and customizability. I'm looking for a reason that `.` can't be overloaded while `->` can and `!` can -- it seems very arbitrary.

Comment: @ereOn: That's the pointer-to-member dereference operator (direct).  There's also an indirect version, `->*`.

Comment: i want range operator `:`.   and a pony.

Comment: @Tim: `->` overloads return a pointer, because `->` operates on pointers.  Would `.` overloads return a copied value?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Thanks. I have never seen it anywhere.

Comment: @ereOn it's one of the two operators for dereferencing pointers to class members. The other is `->*`, which as far as I know uses the implementation for operator->() of the left hand side of the expression.

Comment: @aaa: New operators are a different topic entirely.

Comment: @Tim: Overloading neither `->` nor `!` restricts one from using basic, fundamental C++ features. This is not the case for `.`.

Comment: Here you go: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/whitespace98.pdf

Comment: @Tomalak: A pointer or a smart pointer.  Because `->` is going to get used on the result.  Chaining is a peculiarity of overloading `->`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: What about a pointer or a smart pointer?

Comment: @Ben: according to Stroustrup (linked from bta's answer), overloaded `operator.` could return a reference. Possibly it could also be allowed to return an object. Doesn't seem to me like a reason not to allow the overload.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To quote Bjarne Stroustrup:

> There is no fundamental reason to
>   disallow overloading of ?:. I just
>   didn't see the need to introduce the
>   special case of overloading a ternary
>   operator. Note that a function
>   overloading expr1?expr2:expr3 would
>   not be able to guarantee that only one
>   of expr2 and expr3 was executed.

...

> Operator . (dot) could in principle be
>   overloaded using the same technique as
>   used for ->. However, doing so can
>   lead to questions about whether an
>   operation is meant for the object
>   overloading `.` or an object referred to
>   by `.` ... This problem can be solved in
>   several ways. At the time of
>   standardization, it was not obvious
>   which way would be best.

[Source](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#overload-dot)

Comment: Nice to see why straight from Mr Stroustrup!

Comment: The second quote basically says that if you have `a.b`, and the type of `a` has overloaded `operator.`, it would be hard to determine whether `b` is to be applied on the instance `a` or on the result of `type::operator.(a)` (I am using the function syntax instead of a member function syntax as that could be confusing, what does `a.operator.` mean?)

Comment: @Tim: no, we don't have the same problem with `a+b`. `a+b` must mean either `operator+(a,b)` or `a.operator+(b)`, whichever exists, because there is no built-in meaning of `+` for arbitrary objects. Look at the example in bta's link to see the issue Stroustrup is talking about. It doesn't arise with `operator+` overloads, or even with `operator->` overloads (in which you follow the indirection to the end, then look for members). But according to Stroustrup he thought of several sensible resolutions for `operator.` overloads and could not choose between them.

Answer (score 7):

If you overload `.`, how would you access class members? What would be the meaning of `obj.data`?

Comment: but still `->`can, so then again what would be the meaning of `obj->data`?

Comment: @TommyA: Exactly. If you overload both (`.` and `->`), then you cannot really access the class members. Since one is already allowed, then disallowing the other makes sense, and avoids lots of problem!

Comment: @TommyA: It allows a smart pointer object to feel like a real (raw) pointer.  Please note that `->` is a VERY special case.  It's a binary operator, but only the left-hand side is used during overloading.  It chains.  And after evaluation, name resolution takes place on the right-hand-side.  All of which are unique behaviors.

Comment: `.` is more basic than `->`. `obj->data` is defined as `(*obj).data`, so overloading it is basically equivalent to overloading the dereferencing operator.

Comment: @TommyA: There is a subtle, but significant difference. When obj is T *, then the meaning is the same as (*obj).data and you cannot overload the -> operator. The interesting case is when obj is T - in that case you are "overloading" -> which has no default implementation.

Comment: @Suma: You're the only person who gave @TommyA the correct answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

What would the syntax be?

In fact, there are good reasons for not overloading any operator
which doesn't evaluate all of its operands: you shouldn't
overload && or || either (except in special cases).  You can't
simulate this with an overloaded operator.  Consider something
like:
    p != NULL ? defaultValue : p->getValue()
where the type of defaultValue or p->getValue() causes overload
resolution to pick up your overload.  It's a common idiom, but
it can't be made to work if you overloaded ?:.

Comment: I agree, but `&&` and `||` _can_ be overloaded, so why not `?:`?

Comment: The original reason was simply syntax, I think.  But having realized that overloading && and || was a mistake, no one was motivated to find the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some reading material [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.5) :)

In general there would be no benefit to overloading the operators above. What additional semantics would you be trying to implement?

The reason for overloading operators is to provide intuitive syntax to the user of your class. For example, it makes sense to overload + and += for strings. It's obvious to another developer what that means.

It's really not obvious what you would overload ?: for ... That said there are no technical reasons I am aware of that prevented these operators from being overloaded.

Overloading the -> operator allows for reference counted pointers to be created such as boost::shared_ptr. The concept of 'negating' an object might have different meanings in different contexts, so it's reasonable to occasionally overload this operator.

Comment: It would make sense to overload `?:` to shorten e.g. `player.is_dead() ? ... :` or `money.value == 0 ? ... : `.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks, I had not heard of it.

Comment: @Tim Nordenfur- That would lead to unexpected behavior.  The function implementing the overloaded `?:` operator would not be able to guarantee that only the 'true' or 'false' branch is executed.  See Bjarne's quote in my answer.

Comment: The 2nd example, money.value == 0 is more like overloading == than ... ? ... : .... And, AFAIK, you can overload ==, so this example isn't the case here.

Comment: @bta: Of course there would be limitations, just like overloading `&&`.

Comment: @silmeth: I was talking about shortening `money.value == 0 ? ... :` to `money ? ... :`. (I'm satisfied with Ben's solution, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Defining "operator bool" is enough for ?: to work.
For operator . think of this: SomeClass."SomeString!!"

These overloadings prohibit compiler's lexer from parsing the file correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to deficiencies in the standard, it is almost never a good idea to overload `operator bool`. C++0x fixes this with the ability to tag conversion operators as explicit, and then fiddling the verbiage of the standard to say that certain cases in which you might think the conversion to `bool` is implied, it's actually explicit. If you want to achieve the effect of overloading `operator bool` pre-C++0x, you should google the 'safe bool idiom'.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can overload most operators is to be able to simulate built in types.  Since none of the built in types can use the `.` operator, it wouldn't serve any purpose.  `operator*` and `operator->` are there so you can make your own pointer classes.  All the math and boolean operators are there to be able to make your own numeric classes.

Comment: But you can overload `&&` and `,`.